# Display block not working for image in floated div

Tags: css, html

I have an image and some text floated next to it. I have a title which I wan't to be on its own line so I set it to display:block but it's not working. I can't for the life of me figure it out. It seems to work when I don't have it floated.

Here is an image to help make it clear. I want the image 'Fin MCool' to be display block
[image]

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/zq7C6/

HTML

```
 <div class="staff">
<img src="../assets/images/fin.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="staffContent">
        <img src="../assets/images/fintitle.png" alt="">
        <p>Stunt pilot with the Red Arrows (UK airforce stunt team), has    served in combat choppers in 3 recent wars, and fears nothing except small dogs and single women.</p>
        <p>Owns an Extra EA-200 for the ultimate full stunt flight experience, and flies all our other fixed wing craft much more sedately when required. And, yes, that is his real name. He's Irish and he doesn't want to talk about it.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .staff{
color:#001D5D;
margin-left: 10px;
 }

.staff img {
float:left;
 }

 .staffContent img {
display: block;
 }

 .staffContent {
width:500px;
float:left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the block display, all images are displayed as block in your code. Your problem is that the second image gets a `float: left` against your wish (you wanted only the first image to float).

This is because the rules of `.staff img` are modifying *all* images in `.staff`, not only the direct child as you probably want. The simplest fix is

`.staff > img {`

The `>` between the selectors means only direct child elements.

Comment: @ev9604 If you are satisfied with the answer, upvoting or/and accepting is a very good reward. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
     .staff
     {
        color:#001D5D;
        margin-left: 10px;
     }
     .staff img 
     {
        float:left;
     }

     .staffContent img 
     {
        display: block;
     }
     .staffContent 
     {
        width:60%;
        float:left;
     }
    .staffContent img
    {
        float: none;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zq7C6/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/zbf3a/)

Css

```
.staffContent img.heading{
    float:none;
}
```

some changes in html

Give class on img .heading under the ***.staffContent*** container.

```
<img src="http://purestrategic.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/typography-unnamed-cbffa-x-hd-jootix-66808-300x168.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="40" class="heading">
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `float:none` to `.staffContent img`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/zq7C6/1/)**